# 2 layouts in a CardView ListView that extends 1 layout only?

Tags: android, sqlite, listview

So I've been searching this for days scouring this forum and other sites for answers/tutorials and still can't figure out if this is even possible.

I want to know if its possible to use a cardview listview that has a date as a "key" and is a header and the rows below populate according to that date key.

Users will be able to populate 2 fields each day. One for an exercise called Burpees and how many they did, as well as how much sets.

That data will be saved into SQLite and will be used to retrieve/populate their progress by day.

Here is a simple scheme that I want to implement in SQLite.

[image]

I would like to create a "history page" that displays a listview that uses a cardview theme. The header will be the date. And the amount of burpees they did ACCORDING to that date.

Here is a template I did in android studio to show how i'd like it to look.
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you should be able to do this.  You would just need to first get a list of all available dates

```
SELECT DISTINCT Date FROM BurpeeHistory
```

Then you will need to query the records by date for each card

```
SELECT * FROM BurpeeHistory WHERE BurpeeHistory.Date = --Card Date Here
```

Comment: I'm sorry. Can you elaborate more?

Comment: Have you started writing any code yet? My answer was specific to using the database for your purpose. Once you build the database in your app, you will need to use similar queries to 1. get a list of unique dates in the database. Each date will represent one card in your UI. 2. For each unique date / card in your UI you will need to query the database doing something similar to the second query. You could possibly do it in a loop, passing in the date for each card in the query, and the result could be used to populate a day object or something that would be the data behind each card in the UI.

Comment: This would be for retrieving the data only, updating would similar. The tricky part would be updating / deleting things because one day/card can be represented by multiple database entries. You would have to delete all the records for a date, and replace it with a new record the user creates. I hope this answers your question and makes sense.

Comment: Yes, I'm sorry again. This time its ME who wasn't more clear. I know how to filter through the data with no problem. My issue isn't so much as SQL. It's mainly more so the idea of how can I just extend ONE ROW of data from a cardview. ALL the tutorials out there show exactly how to do it. But they are predefined/pre-entered arraylists that the programmer enters themselves. Mine are dynamically entered from the user into a SQL DATABASE and retrieved INTO an arraylists. I have tried HashSets, Collections, Iterations from all walks of life from tutorials and here and im still stumped.

Comment: I guess I'm still not quite understanding your question. What exactly do you mean by "extend" one row? Do you mean how do you pull a single row out of the database and into an array and then the card view?

Comment: Yea I may have to change the wordings on my questions. I need to know how to pull data from SQL arraylists. Populate and create a listview with a cardview theme with values according to the date. The listview will carry 2 views. The first view is the date which is the header for EACH cardview. Then the 2nd view is the data corresponding to the date. That is the row I want to keep populating. The header is static, while the "data" row keeps extending based on how much it has.

Comment: Just wanted to say thank you. I REALLLLY had to dig deep into your answer and it was actually correct. It took alot of tinkering and debugging but I got it to work!

Thank you again!

Comment: Hey no problem man!  That is all part of the learning process, good luck.